# Scala match expression as a switch statment

Tags: scala, switch-statement, overhead

I am trying to use a scala match expression as a switch statement. I do not have my case values stored in an array and want to generate it during runtime.

```
while (completedTasks < todoTasks) {
      // Submit if machine 0 is ready.

      if (status(0) == READY)
        submit(0, 1)

      // Submit if machine 0 is failed.
      if (status(0) == FAILED)
        submit(0, 1)
}
```

How can I convert the above piece of code into a match expression.
I am trying to replicate a cloud server and run multiple threads to avoid communication overhead.
Assumen having 10 machine.

Comment: Is not exactly clear what you mean with _"switch statement"_.

Comment: Is your question about `[java]` or `[scala]`? Remove the tag that doesn’t apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pattern matching](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html) on the [ADT Structure](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/case-objects-vs-enumerations).

Here is one of the ways how you can do your example:

```scala
sealed trait Status
case object Ready extends Status
case object Failed extends Status

//Some logic to output READY or FALSE here.
// For example purposes we always return READY.
def status(value: Int): Status = Ready 
                               
status(0) match {
  case Ready => "I'm ready"
  case Failed => "I'm failed"
}
```

You can try out this example in a [playground here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oIc6DQTGR5KZhVMAersvKA).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I have updated the answer with ADT structure. Thank you.